# How to get the index of children in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes

In a Rails 3.2 app I'm using [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) to create a complex form.

The form/ model `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, and I need to get the index of child objects.

The models:

```
class Project
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
end

class Task
  belongs_to :project
end
```

The form

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |builder| %>
    ## I need to get the index of each object built via builder
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How do I correctly get the index?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems this is not possible directly via fields_for. Instead the following approach works.

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
  <% @project.tasks.each.with_index do |task, index| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :tasks, task do |builder| %>

      <%= index %>  #get the index here!!

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You're supposed to be able to access the index through Rails FormHelper http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for-label-One-to-many (it's right at the bottom of that section) but it seems that simple form doesn't support this. Just leaving the link here for any other Googlers.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.index %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```